# jquery ui datepicker icon not on sameline

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

My jquery datepicker icon keeps showing on next line, but should be inline with the textboxfor.  I've narrowed it down to the @class = "form-control input-sm".

here is .net jsfiddle  https://dotnetfiddle.net/GX2oOH

Comment: css problem..need a jsfiddle to look into

Comment: check the jsfiddle i've added

Comment: remove/edit class - form-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to css and reference this class.

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    display: inline;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left:3px;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width:auto; at the end in this line

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Order_Date, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", id = "datepicker-orderdate", style = "width:auto;" })
```

and tell me what happen next please.